# Justificar Texto en Quarto para salida Beamer

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Necesito justificar el texto de un archivo en Quarto que tiene como salida en un archivo en formato Beamer.
Por Favor ayuda con la forma.
Saludos,

P.S. El texto aparece en el documento como el primer párrafo, y necesito que la salida sea como el segundo.
Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un poco más de información y contexto? por ejemplo el código que tienes hasta ahora, un ejemplo de como sale y un ejemplo de como quisieras que salga.

Comment: Hola, agregué dos imágenes. El texto tiene salida como el primer párrafo, y necesito que la salida sea como el segundo. Gracias

Comment: Rehíce tu pregunta con lo que logre interpretar, fijate si esto te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/587772/es-posible-modificar-la-alineaci%c3%b3n-de-un-p%c3%a1rrafo-en-una-presentaci%c3%b3n-beamer-pdf

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho