# ¿Es posible modificar la alineación de un párrafo en una presentación Beamer/PDF?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Tengo el siguiente código `r-markdown` de una presentación en `beamer`:

````
---
title: "Beamer"
author: "Patricio Moracho"
date: "21/3/2023"
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Alineación default

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce imperdiet augue nunc, et congue dui malesuada in. Etiam ultrices ullamcorper lacus eget tincidunt. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum condimentum nulla at dolor iaculis facilisis. Vivamus auctor quis nibh ac accumsan. Cras ultricies quam mattis, molestie felis vel, fringilla odio. Donec congue nisl id lobortis maximus. Proin dapibus ac ligula at semper. Nulla commodo justo mi, sit amet condimentum magna sollicitudin eu. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque non tincidunt enim.
````

Al generar la presentación la salida del texto es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que el texto del párrafo este completamente justificado. Estuve investigando por el lado de `markdown` y se dice que no hay mecanismos nativos para establecer una alineación o justificación del texto. ¿Hay forma de lograr esta justificación?

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente  `markdown` no prevé ninguna forma nativa de justificar el texto, por que ciertamente el lenguaje es "agnóstico" de la presentación final, y la justificación o alineación del texto es absolutamente dependiente del ancho de página, algo que `markdown` ignora por diseño.

Sin embargo, hay algunas alternativas que permiten "conversar" con el procesador de `markdown` para  que que tenga ciertas consideraciones que el lenguaje no soporta.

Una forma sencilla que funciona con el `knit` común de un documento `r-markdowm` es incorporar código `html` para modificar los estilos al comienzo luego de la cabecera `yaml`:

```
<style>
body {text-align: justify}
</style>
```

Con esto modificamos la justificación del cuerpo completo del documento, pero no debería ser difícil ajustar esto a bloque de párrafos específicos. Sin embargo, **esto no funciona para las presentaciones en `beamer`**, tal vez por que la generación no trabaje con código `html` intermedio. Para esto, la posibilidad que tenemos es incorporar código `latex` directamente en el documento:

````
---
title: "Beamer"
author: "Patricio Moracho"
date: "21/3/2023"
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Justificado

\justifying
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce imperdiet augue nunc, et congue dui malesuada in. Etiam ultrices ullamcorper lacus eget tincidunt. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum condimentum nulla at dolor iaculis facilisis. Vivamus auctor quis nibh ac accumsan. Cras ultricies quam mattis, molestie felis vel, fringilla odio. Donec congue nisl id lobortis maximus. Proin dapibus ac ligula at semper. Nulla commodo justo mi, sit amet condimentum magna sollicitudin eu. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque non tincidunt enim.
````

Notas:

- Tuvimos que agregar el paquete `ragged2e` en la cabezera `yaml`
- Y luego simplemente agregamos `\justifying` en el párrafo a justificar

Finalmente la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]